# What protects a dog's hearing?

Tags: dogs, hearing

My Weimaraner barks VERY loudly (146dB measured with a precision meter)

What protects the dog's eardrums from this extreme noise?   My human ears are stunned by this volume and would certainly be damaged if I did not block the noise. Dogs cannot block it - so what is the mechanism that protects them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply speaking, when a dog barks, the positive pressure on the ear canal created by the physical motions of the bark close off, protecting the ear; much the same as you covering your ears. From Per Jensen, "The Behavioral Biology of Dogs."

> ...the utricle is activated immediately before a dog starts to bark and therefore offers protection to its own ear

For more detailed info, you can read at [WikiVet](https://en.wikivet.net/Ear_-_Anatomy_%26_Physiology)

Comment: Thank you!  And that expains why she doesn't hear me when she is barking !

Comment: My pleasure. It's a great question